# Xcode Mapkit zoom to current location

Tags: xcode, location

I have a map based iphone app that currently shows user locations and annotations pulled through json. I'm trying to create a button so that it zooms and centers on the user's current location. I have found the following code:

- (IBAction)showCurrentLocation {
  [mapView setCenter:mapView.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
  }

and understand that this can help however everywhere I paste this code I get errors. Does anyone know the steps to make this work/if this is the correct approach?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
- (IBAction)showCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
self.mapview.showsUserLocation=YES;
self.mapview.delegate = self;
[self.mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
}
```